# How can I position: fixed an element relative to the parent container?

Tags: html, css

I have a container that will have a dynamic height and 100% width. I am trying to place an X to close the modal I have made. But I am trying to be creative with overflow scroll. When the user scrolls through the text I would like the close button to be fixed to the top of the container - not the window. Is this possible? Note - I am using a hard height for the example. I am also trying to avoid javascript and jQuery.

```css
.otherContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 2em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  z-index: 1;
}

.parentContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 2em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.Content {
  position: relative;
 }
 
 .close {
  position: fixed;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 999;
 }
```

```html
<div class="otherContent"></div>
<div class="parentContainer">
  <div class="Content">
  <div class="close">X</div>
    Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make the `X` have absolute positioning outside the `<div class="Content">` but still inside the `<div class="parentContainer">`?

Comment: `Fixed` positioning will always anchor the element to your browser, not the container it's at.

Comment: That's not true, @Hewlett. It will position relative to active viewport and that's not necessarily the browser window. (But the browser window is the active viewport by default.)

Comment: I see. Thanks for correcting me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.otherContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 2em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  z-index: 1;
}

.parentContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 2em;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.Content {
  position: relative;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 200px;
 }

 .close {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 2em;
  z-index: 999;
 }
```

Live JsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/drmrd59d/

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
.close {
  position: absolute;
}
```

I hope it answer